# How to access json data using string variable parameter?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I need to access json data

[see format on this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/31fXf.png)

sample 
   Object {BD: Object, BE: Object, BF: Object, BG: Object, BA: Object…}
AD
:
Object
AE
:
Object
AF
:
Object
AG
:
Object
AI
:
Object
AL
:
Object
AM
:
Object
Code ,i am using

```
var otherna = $('#othernation').text();
// BE a String value
```

when i use manual to get value it works

```
$.getJSON('/skins/all.json', function(data) {
                console.log(data.Results.BE);
            });
```

I got

```
Object {Name: "Belgium", Capital: Object, GeoRectangle: Object, SeqID: 20, GeoPt: Array(2)…}
```

when i pass this variable otherna value

```
  $.getJSON('/skins/all.json', function(data) {
                console.log(data.Results.otherna);
            });
```

I got this error undefined

please help me for this issue thanks.

Comment: Could you post your HTML code also so we can see what #othernation is?

Comment: I found answer from  Alexander Thank you Alexander it works data.Results[otherna]